# Apple Mach-O Linker Error - Phonegap Paypal Plugin

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

Hi I'm trying to implement the Phonegap Paypal Plugin (https://github.com/searchtool/PayPalPlugin) but cannot get it to compile - I receive the following errors in Xcode..

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s:
 "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PayPalInvoiceItem", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in SAiOSPaypalPlugin.o
 "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PayPalPayment", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in SAiOSPaypalPlugin.o
 "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PayPal", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in SAiOSPaypalPlugin.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7s
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I've followed the recommendations in similar SO posts - all files added by right clicking the project and using the 'add files to 'method.  But always get linker errors!  No idea where to begin - any advice?

Comment: Try enabling `Build Active Architecture Only` by setting its value `YES`

Comment: Cheers Deepesh - no luck though..

Comment: Did you checked whether the plugin is listed in `Target -> Build Phases -> Link with binary libraries`

Comment: Hi Deepesh - yes its in there

Answer (score 0):

The static library you're trying to use hasn't been compiled for the armv7s architecture, only armv6 and armv7. To test this, rather than enabling `Build Active Architecture Only` try *removing* armv7s from your architectures and see if that works. If it does, you can then work on getting the library compiled up to armv7s.

Comment: Cheers lxt - though it didn't work when I enabled 'build architecture only', so would this fix work?  Also - there isn't an option for armv6 in the architecture drop down - so I've no idea how to remove/change the architecture?  Sorry my xcode experience is pretty limited!

Comment: You should be able to add armv7 in. armv6 has been deprecated, which is why you can't see it. Your active architecture is probably set to armv7s, which is why it isn't working.

Comment: cheers - I've edited the 'valid architectures' field and removed armv7s - (is this the way to do it?) - I still get the errors though unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

This plugin has been re-written and should not contain these bugs anymore. It can be found at https://github.com/SnareChops/PayPalPlugin and has been successfully tested in PayPal's sandbox environment.